# How to add an ID to react-table component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to add a unique id to a bunch of react-tables I have created.
I created a custom component that uses react-table.

I've tried adding the id prop to the  tag but that is not working, I'm guessing that's because there is no id prop defined on the library ?

```
return <ReactTable data={props.data} columns={columns} showPagination={false} minRows={5} style={{height :"400px"}} id='someId'/>;
```

I was expecting for this to add the id attribute into the the div created by the react-table library but that's not happening

Comment: Wrap the <ReactTable> element with a <div> and give that <div> an id.
`return <div id='someId'><ReactTable data={props.data} columns={columns} showPagination={false} minRows={5} style={{height :"400px"}} id='someId'/></div>`

Comment: question is, why do you need an id? if you want to access it you should do it the react way using a ref.

Comment: Automation team asked for them, just because of that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like React Table handles this via the `getProps` attribute on the ReactTable element, which takes a callback that should return your custom attributes.  Try the below snippet in your `render()` function.

```
const customProps = { id: 'my-table-id' };

return (
  <ReactTable
    data={props.data}
    columns={columns}
    showPagination={false}
    minRows={5}
    style={{height :"400px"}}

    getProps={() => customProps}
  />
);
```

Comment: Thanks - feel free to upvote and accept, using the up-arrow and checkmark in the upper left of this post. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I already did :) my upvote doesn't show up because I'm too new, but I checkmarked it as well. Thanks again!